# Как поменять цвет темы windows 10 через приложение c#?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, forms, themes

Возник вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при условном нажатии на кнопку цвет приложений менялся на темный, а потом на светлый? Интересует просто переключение между этими двумя параметрами, не более того. То есть саму тему на другую менять не надо.[image: Параметры персонализации]

Comment: [схожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774307/c-get-windows-8-1-10-selected-color-theme)

Comment: [ещё решение для WPF](https://quares.ru/?id=435457)